# How to install Ubuntu20.04 on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, software-installation

While upgrading to Ubuntu 20.10 from 20.04 i killed the process after i read 20.04 is longer supported and 20.10 is just end last year, well i don't know that, but it's too late, some program stop working like terminal, file manager ang settings. I want to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 but how ?

I don't have dual boot and "i can't login in my Ubuntu anymore" but i have ubuntu20.04 in my flash drive for re-installation please tell me what should i do to do that.

Comment: As Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/) you haven't been able to *release-upgrade* to it since 2021-June-18 so either you're asking about something that you did months ago - or facts are incorrect - please check. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is a *long-term-support* release which is supported until 2025-April without the need of ESM (which will extend's its support for a further 5 years).

Comment: If a *release-upgrade* was running; you should be specific as to what command was being used; and where it was up to when you *killed* it (it's unclear given you state facts that haven't been possible since June-2021!).  If you were still downloading packages; no impact should have occurred - if packages were being installed; you'll need to restore your backups...  If it's a desktop install; I'd *upgrade via re-install* (ie. re-install without format) which will allow you to go forward or return to 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Can i use (advance option for ubuntu) to install Ubuntu 20.04 again ?

Comment: No, you need to create a bootable USB to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. What exactly happened while upgrading? How were you upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04? From which release were you upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04? Your question has several typos, mistakes, etc. Please [edit] to make it more clear!

Comment: The Answer said (Start the installation from a live USB or DVD of Ubuntu 20.04.) but where? advance option for ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall 20.04 over an existing installation of Ubuntu 20.04 without erasing user data.

- Start the installation from a live USB or DVD of Ubuntu 20.04.
- When given the choice about the installation mode, select "Something else".
- You see a screen with a map of the partitions on your drive. Manually assign your old root partition to be the root partition (`/`) of the new installation. If you had a swap partition, assign that partition as swap. If you had a separate partition for `/home`, assign that  partition to be mounted to `/home`. **Important:** Make sure to **uncheck** " Format.
- Proceed with the installation

This way of installing will essentially refresh all system files, without erasing user data and user configuration data. This is the quickest way to restore your system to a working 20.04 installation.

*Note:* Your upgrade from the supported 20.04 LTS release to 20.10 did not work anymore, because 20.10 is not anymore supported. Currently, your only upgrade path will be to the forthcoming LTS 22.04.